# Tibco spotfire ,implement into web page

Tags: node.js, web-applications, spotfire, tibco

I have a node js app ,i want to expose my analysis that i did on spotfire on my web page .

I managed to use containers but it exposes the whole dashboard i need help to just expose only one virsualisation .

please help ,how do i do it ?